# How can I reach and compare the data?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, matrix

I have created a matrix with pointer to pointers.

```
int** matrix = new int*[5];
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[5];
```

If I assume correctly, what this does is it creates a pointer named matrix, which points to an array of pointers, and each pointer in the array points to an integer array, which array's items consist of integer type data.
I have written in number this way:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = 6 + j;
```

And here comes my problem: when I try to compare items from my matrix, the if statement does not compare the data stored inside the matrix, but it compares the items' memory addresses.

```
if(matrix[i][0] == matrix[i][j])
```

How can I solve this problem? I have tried a lot of different things, but none has worked so far. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Write a sub-function that actually compares the values.

Comment: But how can I do that?
**(matrix[i][0]) == **(matrix[i][j])
This won't work

Comment: for loop through the entire array and compare each element.

Comment: I have the for loop already, this way:

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
   for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
      if(matrix[i][0] == matrix[i][j])

This is not working, it is comparing the MEMORY ADDRESSES of the items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot dereference any further, as `matrix[i][j]` resolves to the actual value (the integer) inside the matrix.

I tested with this code:

```
cout << "Value of matrix[0][0]: " << matrix[0][0] << endl;
cout << "Pointer to matrix[0][0]: " << &matrix[0][0] << endl;
```

Which gave me:

```
Value of matrix[0][0]: 6
Pointer to matrix[0][0]: 0x1705040
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I could figure it out at last.

Comment: If I run this, `if (matrix[0][0] == matrix[1][0]) {cout << "Equals" << endl;}`, your program outputs "Equals". This illustrates that the value '6' of [0][0] and [1][0] is compared.